# why below regular expression doesn't match the string?

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the below string with Regular expression

string             : PKGx.1234 ... BBA
Regular expression : ^\bPKG[0-9]{0,1}.[0-9]{0,4}\ ...\ \bBB[A-B]{1}?$

but i am getting no match error

can anyone help me with how can i remodify the regular expression to match the given string ..?

Comment: There is `x` after `PKG` but you use `[0-9]{0,1}`. Also, there is a space and comma at the end of the string, you require the end of string right after `BBA`. Try something like `^PKG[0-9A-Za-z]?\.[0-9]{0,4}\ \.\.\.\ BB[AB]\b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a character `x` after PKG that the pattern tries to match with an optional digit `[0-9]?` If there should be an optional single a lowercase character, you can use `[a-z]?` instead.

You can omit the word boundary before the `BB` as there is an implicit word boundary in between.

Note that you don't have escape the spaces, but you do have to escape the dot to match it literally.

```
^PKG[a-z]?\.[0-9]{0,4} \.{3} BB[A-B]\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZBZy1v/1)

If you want to match the whole string including the space and comma at the end, including using the `$` anchor to assert the end of the string:

```
^PKG[a-z]?\.[0-9]{0,4} \.{3} BB[A-B] , *$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fhkHg6/1)